# Object HTML tag not working

Tags: html

I am trying to embed a PDF on a web page, but it isn't showing up.  This is the code:

```
<object type="application/pdf" data="http://www.sunshinesam.com/v/vspfiles/downloadables/Father'sDayPrintable2015.pdf" height="600" width="400">Father's Day Printable 2015</object>
```

What do I need to change to make it work?  Thanks!

Comment: try including a link to your pdf inside the object?

Comment: I don't want a link -- I need to embed the PDF in the page.

Comment: Found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319484/pdf-embedded-in-object-or-embed-tag-not-loading-in-ie-11

Comment: oh, nice! sorry i couldn't be of more help!

Answer (score -1):

A pure, non-javascript way to this would be to do exactly what you're doing now, but add a link. Some thing like

```
    <object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
  <p>Alternative text - include a link <a href="myfile.pdf">to the PDF!</a></p>
</object>
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  I don't want a link to the PDF -- I want to embed it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081128/how-can-i-embed-a-pdf-viewer-in-a-web-page does this help? it has a bunch of solutions.

Comment: Hey, you copied the first solution from your link!