# PDF embed not working on IE with current code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, iframe

Before I include the code I'm working with, please know that I have tried an iframe but had a problem with displaying content inside the iframe in IE. To see what I'm talking about.. Please check out this link, in both Chrome and then Explorer: http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Also, ^ this link is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, but so that it shows for IE as well..

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Display PDF in-page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="flyer_builder.css" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
             $("#myDiv").load("pdf.html");
          });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid flyer-builder">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a id="refresh" href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Refresh PDF</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="myDiv"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
          $("#refresh").click(function(evt) {
             $("#myDiv").load("pdf.html")
          })
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script in the head allows it to load on initial page load, the script towards the bottom of the body refreshes just that part of the page. This all works great in chrome, but still doesn't work in IE!!! Help please.

pdf.html: (I've used a generic pdf file for example purposes)

```
<object data="https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width:100%;">
    <embed src="https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf" type="application/pdf"/>
</object>
```

Comment: Have you seen this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319484/pdf-embedded-in-object-or-embed-tag-not-loading-in-ie-11. Accepted answer recommends `<iframe>` over `<embed>` (or `<object>`) for display on IE.

Comment: @dwarring you're right!! and thanks for the share, I just answered my own question with some useful code, check it out and test if you want. It would help me so much if you could upvote my answer!

Comment: @dwarring I went about it with both iframe and object->embed ways, but both of these solutions just wouldn't work with some PDFs in IE. I finally found a solution and posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All has been solved thanks to a wonderful resource: PDFObject: http://pdfobject.com/

Generates something similar to an iframe/object-embed, but works in all IE v9+, FireFox, Chrome Browsers.